# When asked about the electrical field at the focal length, why do we use Fresnel Region?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

Textbook asks to calculate the electric field at the focal point of a convex lens. Why is it the Fresnel region?

Comment: The Fresnel region allows you to use a simpler method the do the calculation. The problem implies conditions that places it in the Fresnel region. Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @flippiefanus Not homework, and they imply no other condition.

Comment: Any physical convex lens has a finite aperture and a given focal length. The focal length is usually much larger than the aperture. This places you in the Fresnel region.